# Problems installing virtualenvwrapper in OSX 10.11.3

Tags: python, macos, bash, opencv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm new to programming and python but have been learning it for a couple of months. My objective is to install openCV3 for Python3.5.1. For this, I've been following this tutorial: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/29/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-osx/

My problem is I can't seem to install virtualenvwrapper correctly. When I reload my .bash_profile, terminal tells me "bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory".

During the installation phase, terminal returned the following:

```
Gwenns-New-MBP:~ gwennlaine$ pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenvwrapper in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv-clone in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stevedore in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pbr>=1.6 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
Collecting six>=1.9.0 (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 725, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 752, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 266, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/kd/k4jl6x895ydcsk0mcx1pnvp40000gn/T/pip-A3qhrB-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

I should note I have tried many different this/alternate ways to install this, and have spent now two days on google researching the issue, but nothing seems to work!

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Gwenn

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're trying to install virtualenvwrapper via python 3 but osx it's using python 2.7. Do you have python3 installed?

Comment: do a which pip3 on the command line, and see if you get the correct version of pip3

Comment: it returns "/usr/local/bin/pip3". should it not say that?

Comment: type this into the command to see if the file actually exists. ls /usr/local/bin/virtual*. you also have to upgrade python 2.7 and not use the one that comes with the mac. did you install python 2.7 from homebrew too?

Comment: It returns: 
"/usr/local/bin/virtualenv /usr/local/bin/virtualenv-clone
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv-3.5" The Python 2.7 is the one which came with El Capitan... The 3.5.1 version was installed using Home brew. I don't think virtualenv poses a problem though: it's really virtualenvwrapper which doesn't seem to install anywhere...

Comment: Yes but from the above error it says it already meet the requirements but from 2.7. Which would mean that for some reason pip3 is pointing to Python 2.7.

Comment: Whenever I try to install virtual env using pip3 mine says it already meets the requirements from 3.4

Answer (score 0):

So, I was so fed up with trying to achieve this that I went another route. I installed pyenv. I then installed pyenv-virtualenv and pyenv-virtualenvwrappers as plugins. This allowed me to create a stable and isolated virtual environment to install and compile OPenCV3. Some commands are different compared to normal virtualenv, but overall, it achieves the same thing!